# Sending MIDI via usb on Android

Tags: android, processing, midi

I'm doing a preliminary research to convert a simple midi sequencer designed with Processing in an Android app, the problem is that the library that I use on the computer to interface with music devices via MIDI does not work inside android. So I decided to export the project to Android Studio.
There are several Google Samples about MIDI, but none showing how to send an outgoing MIDI signal via USB to a listening music device.

Do you know if there is any example for android studio that deals with the topic? Any advice?

I could develope it entirely on Processing but the Processing the MidiBus MIDI library does not work on Android.

Thanks

Comment: If you are ready to write a bit of C++ there is a library called superpowered . Otherwise use the OSC protocol via WIFI.

Comment: Hi @mpm very interesting lib since i also work with adaptive streaming but for this kind i guess that android.media.midi could help me to close this exercise.
But at "Check for Feature Support" i'm unable to understand where to put the line and if all the midi code need to be inside this line. I try to build my midi output port to trig an external musical device when a "full step" is blinking. if you want i can share the entire project, it's short and simple :)

Comment: What hardware are you using to connect USB MIDI devices to the Android device?

Comment: In this moment i don't use anything, cause the output port is not ready, so i'm not ready to do betatest, i could think to link the usb port of the Samsung S7 that i use for my preliminary test to my sound card apogee duet that have USB MIDI port too.

Comment: do you think i need some special cable and not a simple usb cable from android device to sound card?

Comment: You would need at least an OTG cable, but I don't know if the Duet is a class-compliant device and works with Android's standard drivers.

Comment: Thanks for support, this is my purpose, but i can also test it with an usb to midi jack on musical hardwares, apogee duet has a midi/usb female jack input, a common standard today for many controllers, I'm moving this topic on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177610/android-midi-sequencer-with-processing-interface where i explain better my intent.